# Handling OnPreferenceChangeListener in API11

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

Is there a way of handling an OnPreferenceChangeListener in API11. Simply calling Preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener throws a lint error stating it requires API14+, however my app is designed for API11+ and I don't want to limit the number of devices it can run on further.

Update: I have checked in the development documentation and this should be available from API1

Edit: Code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.SwitchPreference;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
private static final String tag = "PREFERENCES";
SwitchPreference appPower;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_layout);

    setupPreferenceElements();

    LogHelper.i(tag, "Preferences Activity Started");
}

private void setupPreferenceElements() {
    appPower = (SwitchPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference(
            "power");
    appPower.setChecked(SettingsManager.getPower());
    appPower.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            LogHelper.i(tag, "App Power Changed to " + newValue.toString());
            SettingsManager.setPower(Boolean.parseBoolean(newValue
                    .toString()));
            return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I just made a test app (min API: 8, target: 10 and then min: 13, target: 14) and had no issue in either case. We will need to see some code to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I can give the actual line that's causing issues. What else would you need?

Comment: Em... your imports perhaps and obviously any other lines that logically go together with the one that gives the error. But before we go too far what IDE are you using? Have you tried to "refresh" the project, "clean up" the code and restart your IDE? Sometimes turning it off and on again is the solution. =0p

Comment: I've added my code in. I am using Eclipse. Yep have tried clean, which didn't work

Comment: Think I've found the problem, answer submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`android.preference.SwitchPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) was only added in API v14 (along with [`TwoStatePreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html) in case your first though was to use that instead)

If you want to continue using SwitchPreference for 14+ and support 13- you will need to:

- make a folder `res/xml-v14/`
- have your current `preferences.xml` with your SwitchPreference
- make another folder (if needed) `res/xml/` with another `preferences.xml` and change your SwitchPreference to a CheckBoxPreference.

This will then load the correct version depending on the API version used. You will need to check for API version in your Java code too.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    appPower = new SwitchPreference(this);
} else {
    appPower = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
}
```

If you don't like the CheckboxPreference you can always `extend Preference` or `extend CheckboxPreference` and roll your own solution. This may actually be the best solution as it would have the advantage of being able to wrap both versions in one class where you can then support your preferred implementation, ensuring the methods you want to use are exposed and do not fail, without manual version checks type casting everywhere you use the Preference.

While doing a bit of searching, I stumbled across [this library](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) you might use. It aims to make a support SwitchPreference. I can't speak to how well it works that or if you should use it though, I've never tried it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and post back.

Comment: @RobertEves92, Update, I've added a section on how to handle the differing versions in your code too.

Comment: Is there any way of testing the code for API13- on an API14+ device?

Comment: No. You should be using an emulator for this kind of testing. I'd suggest Genymotion and VirtualBox over the default emulator. Easy to set up too just make sure you grab the Eclipse add-on too if you want to start emulators from within Eclipse. All instructions on the [Genymotion site](http://www.genymotion.com/)